# Как достучатся к TextBlock, если он находится в ListView?

Tags: c#, wpf

Как в c# достучатся до **tbStatus** ?

```
 <ListView  x:Name="listBook"   BorderThickness="0"  Background="Transparent">

                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Border 
                                    Canvas.Top="30"
                                    Width="100"                                
                                    Margin="0 5 0 5"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"       
                                    BorderBrush="Blue"
                                    BorderThickness="1"
                                    CornerRadius="10">

                                    <Border.Effect>
                                        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="20"
                                              Opacity=".5"
                                              ShadowDepth="1" />
                                    </Border.Effect>

                                    <Border Name="ReceiverColor"
                                            BorderBrush="#FF96B2E4"
                                            BorderThickness="2"
                                            CornerRadius="10">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Border Name="Mask"
                                                Background="White"
                                                BorderBrush="#FF3B5998"
                                                BorderThickness="0"
                                                CornerRadius="10">
                                            </Border>
                                            <StackPanel>
                                                <Image Stretch="Fill" Margin="5">
                                                    <Image.Source>
                                                        <Binding Path="Image">
                                                            <Binding.TargetNullValue>
                                                                <ImageSource>
                                                                    /Resources/imageNull.png
                                                                </ImageSource>

                                                            </Binding.TargetNullValue>

                                                        </Binding>
                                                    </Image.Source>
                                                </Image>
                                                <StackPanel.OpacityMask>
                                                    <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=Mask}" />
                                                </StackPanel.OpacityMask>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Border>
                                </Border>


                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding NameBook}" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="110 9 0 0" Style="{StaticResource tbListView}" FontSize="20"/>

                                <TextBlock Text="Автор книги:"  Margin="110 45 0 0" Style="{StaticResource tbListView}"/>

                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding  AuthorOfThebook}"  Margin="205 45 0 0"  Style="{StaticResource tbListView}"/>



                                <TextBlock Text="Год издания:"  Margin="110 65 0 0" Style="{StaticResource tbListView}"/>

                                <Button Style="{StaticResource btnDocumentText}" Content="Электронная версия"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="110 75 0 0"/>

                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding YearOfPublication, StringFormat=MM.dd.yyyy}"
                                           Margin="205 65 0 0"  Style="{StaticResource tbListView}"/>


                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding BookLocation.TypeOfHall.NameZal, StringFormat=MM.dd.yyyy}"
                                           Margin="0 0 20 10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                           HorizontalAlignment="Right" x:Name="tbStatys"
                                           Style="{StaticResource tbListView}"/>
                            </Grid>

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

Comment: как именно достучаться? в коде? по имени? `tbStatus.Text=...`

Comment: @Pekor, да, именно так. Но он не виден в коде. Пробовал ещё вот так название ListView. элемент ... Так тоже не видет. Может что то не правильно пишу.

Comment: ээ, чего-то я в коде не заметил `<TextBlock name="tbStatus"/>`, может ты забыл объявить имя у элемента?

Comment: @Pekor, Так, а вот тут подробнее . А как имя элементу давать ?

Comment: Не надо мучать контролы, используйте привязки данных. Имена контролам при этом не нужны. Не вы должны запихивать в контролы данные, а они сами должных их забирать и обновлять. В WPF всё наоборот работает.

Comment: @aepot, а я и не хочу пихать туда данные, я хочу сделать проверку на текст. Если там текст такой, то цвет текста такой иначе ...

Comment: Trigger/DataTrigger в стиле вам в помощь

Comment: @aepot, понял спасибо

Comment: действительно, если тебе хочется делать так, как ты сейчас делаешь, а именно обращаться к контролам в коде, то лучше использовать WinForms, хотя НИКТО не может тебе запретить или сказать как правильно тебе разрабатывать программу - это лишь разные подходы, что-то лучше, что-то хуже, но ты можешь делать так, как тебе удобнее хоть в WinForms, хоть в WPF. Что касается твоего вопроса - ответ ниже.

Answer (score 0):

Тебе нужно для начала нужному `TextBlock'у` задать имя в XAML разметке, примерно так:

```
 <TextBlock x:Name="tbStatus"/>
```

А потом уже обращаться в коде к элементу таким образом:

```
tbStatus.Text = "Text"
```

Однако, если ты хочешь (как сказал aepot), то можно использовать [DataTrigger](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.datatrigger?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) и/или [Trigger](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.trigger?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)

Comment: ну имя у текст блока задан  <TextBlock Text="{Binding BookLocation.TypeOfHall.NameZal, StringFormat=MM.dd.yyyy}"
                                           Margin="0 0 20 10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                           HorizontalAlignment="Right" x:Name="tbStatys"
                                           Style="{StaticResource tbListView}"/>

Comment: x:Name  -  это и есть имя

Comment: Но я сделал через тригер это